# Couldn't find the Socket running in the iis server in the iisnode webconfig to run socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, iis-10, iisnode

I am running IIS 10 and using iisnode I have to run my socket io (node) application . I have copied my ChatApp application inside www folder. I have added the web.config and added the below lines.

```
 <handlers>
  <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>
```

I have added the below socket connection

```
const io = socketio(server, { path: '/node/ChatApp/socket.io'});
```

And I am running my client in a different application. The connection string is

```
var socket = io('http://localhost', {path: "/node/ChatApp/socket.io"});
```

I couldn't connect the socket. I am getting following error

```
socket.io.js:7 GET http://localhost/node/ChatApp/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MGsBu-c 404 (Not Found)
```

Let me know where I am missing? I know that I am missing the path somewhere. But I couldn't get whether my socket server running properly.

Note: I haven't add the rewirte url in the web.config.

But Without Iisnode I can able to connect and run the socket

Answer (score 0):

Your socket should just be running on your server directly and not through your path.
So try on your client site either:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost');
```

or

```
var socket = io();
```

Comment: But I am running my socket server in a specific path right? I mean my server application is running in the url http://localhost/node/ChatApp/index.js. Even I am getting the 404 error when I remove the path in the client side.
socket.io.js:7 GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MGsWEz4 404 (Not Found)

Comment: yes tried that too. The same Issue I am getting GET localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MGsWEz4 404 (Not Found)